# Div Toggle With php and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I posted this yesterday but was clear there was not enough detail.

https://www.jenkinsdesigns.com/clientsite/dori/portfolio.php - LINK

On the left hand side there is a dynamic category list that pulls categories from a database and shows each one. By default when the page loads it will show everything in another table called portfolio but I want it to work so when you click a category it will remove that past statement about showing them all and only show ones with a category = 4 EG

```
SELECT * FROM portfolio
```

^ Show all Items

```
SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE (category='4')
```

Only show items in a certain category. I can do the SQL part but I am getting very confused on how to show the different categories when they click it. The current structure in the database for the category is

id | name

And the portfolio is

id  |  name  |  category  | description

Is this even possible?

Comment: PHP isn't a client side language.  You'll most likely want Javascript for this unless you want to re-render the entire page from the server when they click.

Comment: But how would I load different category items in?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to go about tackling the issue here.

You could do it all in the front end through some extra parameters and css and javascript. Then you would change your crashItem() call to pass in say the class of the clicked icon, then hide all entries not in that class, and only show those that were.

I think where you're getting tripped up is otherwise, you're going to need to communicate back to the server when someone clicks the button that you'd like the updated details. Usually that's done with an ajax call, which would contain the details of which set to display (category='4'), and then you would parse out the results of that call and manipulate the DOM accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have come to a conclusion.

I am just going to re-load the page on button push with something like this portfolio.php?id=10
then if $_GET['id'] exists it will show items in that category.

Thanks :)